# How to reroute traffic to an ip to a specific port to display website

Tags: spring-boot, networking, https, ip, port

So this is a very basic question. I built a small spring boot web app. It runs on port 8089.
I want to take the website live. So i bought a domain that points to the IPv4 address of my server. As i can't specify a port on my dns server, traffic won't reach my application.

How do i get my website to be displayed?

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute this command. I am assuming that your server is linux server.

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8089
```

This command is to route all the traffic you receive on port 80 to port 8089

Comment: i run an ubuntu instance yes! 
worked fine! thanks alot